# query order by category

Tags: categories, query-posts

i have this line..  in sidebar..

```
<?php query_posts ( ( array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 12)));?>
```

i want to order by category not random.. 
so if i am in a post from category animals.. i want to show 12 post just from this category. 
Not Random like now..

how can i do that?

Comment: Do you have one category per post?  If you can have multiple categories per post how would you expect posts that have multiple categories to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

This should limit the posts pulled in the new WP_Query instance to the currently selected category or the first category of the current post.

```
global $wp_query;
$sidebar_query_vars = array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 12);
if(is_category()) {
    $sidebar_query_vars['cat'] = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
} elseif (is_single()) {
    $categories = (get_the_terms($wp_query->get_queried_object_id(), 'category'));
    if(is_array($categories)) {
        $first_cat = array_shift($categories);
        $sidebar_query_vars['cat'] = $first_cat->term_id;
    }
}
$sidebar_query = new WP_Query($sidebar_query_vars);
while($sidebar_query->have_posts()): $sidebar_query->the_post();
//do output here
endwhile;
```

Comment: Last line should read: ‘$sidebar_query = new WP_Query($sidebar_query_vars);‘, right?

Comment: is not working..it shows me just 1 post and is the same post i am in..

Comment: I updated the code to include the loop.  That was missing from my previous answer.

Comment: i replace this line  < ? php query_posts ( ( array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 12)));?>  with your code.. and still show me just 1 post and is same post i am in..  i do something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Joshmax23: Your original code uses `query_posts()`, which sets the "normal" `$wp_query` variable to hold the loop. This answer uses `$sidebar_query`, so you should adapt your loop to also start with `while ( $sidebar_query->have_posts() ) ...` like in the answer.

Comment: i can`t handle it..  i`m not a coder..   dont know what should i change..